# Is it valid to reask (many) question on same script?

Tags: discussion, asking-questions

I have asked a question about a Python script a few months ago. Now I have developed that script furthermore fixing the issues described in the answer of that question.

Now I have another questions approaching in my mind for that script.

So, what should I do? Should I update the question? *(This is not good because answers were given according to my real old question)*. Or, Should I ask another question referring to old question? *(I'm afraid if my either of the question will be closed.)*

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In general, I think that if you're unsure, asking a question is a sensible approach. If the mods decide that it should be closed, then it will be closed, but that's not a big deal.

In this specific case, I think that you really shouldn't edit your original question. That would mean the original answers would stop making any sense, which would be a very bad thing.

And, assuming you really did take the reviews on your old question in account, I think asking a new question is perfectly fine. Though you should explain the situation and link to the old question.

(Note that in the above, I didn't mean you should follow every single suggestion you got. But if you intentionally ignored some of them, you might want to explain in the new question why did you do that.)

But asking many questions about the same code? That shouldn't be necessary. If two reviews didn't reveal some issue, I don't think three or four will.

Answer (score 2):

I totally agree with Svick and wanted to add this stuff as a comment to his answer but it was a tad too long.

It's way better to ask a new question on the same code if the issue is different, and clearly different, from the first time. This way it will avoid having "outdated" answers on the question. The first question with its specific issues will stay clean. Any other use falling on the question later on will be able to see the answers clearly and understand clearly. Then someone having your second issue will also find the information on the second question you asked and everything will be clear

If you modify the question, that adds stuff and may clutter the question and "outdate" the answers. It may then be harder for people falling on the question to understand what was the issue and what were the answer related to the first issue. Same thing for second issue. Everything will be kind of stuck in one and might be unclear.

Never forget that the site is meant to keep information in order to help future user having similar issues, thus making two question will keep the issues separated and clear.