# Should I ask a separate question?

Tags: discussion, asking-questions, multi-language

This examples applies for web mainly, but could apply for other stuff also.

Let's say I develop a web plugin that has both JavaScript code and CSS.

- Should I post one question to review the JavaScript with its specific issues and one question for the CSS with its specific issue?
- Should I post one big question with both the JavaScript and the CSS with their issues?

I find the first one to be better because JavaScript and CSS are pretty different and have their own issues. Also, one is not dependent of the other; they are totally independent. They both have different coding style.

Also, having one big post would cause the issue whereas two people could have the "right" answer, one for the JS and one for the CSS.

Though having one big post regroup everything at the same place and that can be great too, as you have a more global view of the whole thing.

What do you think?

This question is a bit related to [this question](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/651/is-it-valid-to-reask-many-question-on-same-script) but does not cover exactly the same issue.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would ask two separate questions because (as you said) they are totally independent and smaller questions are easier to answer.
 (You can link them, of course.)

If there is a chance that they are not totally independent I'd consider asking the first question and waiting for a few days or reviews before posting the second one. You might get feedbacks which requires some modification in the code of the second question.

Comment: Well, That's what I've ended up doing, thank you for the answer!

Answer (score 2):

If they are in no way co-dependent I'd ask two separate questions as the context of both pieces of code will be completely different. Also this might only bring up confusion to people who answer the question. What's not needed in a question doesn't belong there and should be left out.

Furthermore the last point of 'palacsint' is indeed important. Best is to ask one of the two and depending on the feedback ask the second question. Which one you want to ask first is depending on the priority of one of the two.

In any case where the JavaScript and CSS are co-dependent, ask both pieces in one question. In a situation for example where JavaScript can influence the CSS, let's say using jQuery, one question would be advised since they are dependent of each other.

Comment: Well, about the day between both question it all depends. Since in my case any change to having to be made on of or the other wouldn't change anything about the other questions, I've decided to ask both at the same time. But I do agree that in most cases it's better to wait a bit of feedback before asking the second one.