# Can I have a question "series" for a major project?

Tags: discussion

I'm about to start my senior computer science project, which involves a web REST API (Rails or Node.js) as well as an Android app. I don't imagine that I'll have a *ton* of questions, but there could be ~10 over the course of 12 weeks.

All questions would be for the same major project, but on different *small, reviewable aspects*. **Is it acceptable to have a question "series" on Code Review?**

PS - I don't plan on using CR as a way to skimp out on doing work. Our team will have regular code reviews for every pull request to each repo, but we're students and are learning the technologies we're using :)

Comment: I have a feeling this question might be a duplicate, but I'm not sure...

Comment: @SimonForsberg I tried searching for a similar question, but couldn't find one... then again my search skills are novice-level, so I may have missed it!

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Yes, you can. In fact one project even has its own tag, [rubberduck](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/rubberduck) (But please don't create a tag for your project at this point in time). Feel free to create as many questions as you want for your project, but I'd recommend to spread them out so that you don't ask them all at the same time. That way you can also learn from previous questions before you ask new ones.

Comment: "But please don't create a tag for your project" why not?

Comment: @Pimgd Excellent question! See [this answer](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/a/5993/31562) for that.

Comment: I always thought the rubberduck tag and chatroom was for "rubberducking" code (explaining it line by line to catch mistakes).

Comment: @CaptainMan FYI tags have extensive wiki descriptions and a short excerpt/summary that explains how to use a tag.

Answer (score 11):

Yes, it's perfectly acceptable. One real example of such projects is [rubberduck](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/rubberduck) which has had enough questions related to the same project that it even has its own tag now.

Of course, your project may not be as expansive as Rubberduck, or warrant having its own tag, but in any case, you are more than welcome to have series of questions related to it.

Answer (score 2):

#### Yes

This has certainly been discussed previously.

Not really a duplicate but [similar](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/q/676/71574).

I'm pretty sure this has been discussed under some other topic.  Here it is [My code is too long. How do I trim it down when code posted here is expected to function?](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1920/71574)

This [FAQ](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3653/71574) directly covers this, albeit briefly.

Note:  while it is off-topic to post a link only question with the code off site, it is on-topic to post a complete section of code with a link to an entire project.  If you do that, it is preferable to link to a specific source control revision rather than a page that can change over time.